# Bootstrap 3: placing a link beside a dropdown control

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to help visitor to select the proper product edition through a link to the Features page. I can't place the `Compare features` link exactly beside the dropdown control.

Do you know how to do?

Thanks.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productForm", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Edition", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("edition", (List<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.PossibleEditions, new { @class = "form-control", onchange="this.form.submit();" })
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Compare features", "Features", "ProductName", null, new { @class = "???" })
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include your rendered html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a column-based layout. You always have 12 columns to use. Since you are using two columns for the label and 10 columns for the dropdown, you are not able to show the link beside the dropdown. You have to use less columns for the dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Edition", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.DropDownList("edition", (List<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.PossibleEditions, new { @class = "form-control", onchange="this.form.submit();" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.ActionLink("Compare features", "Features", "ProductName", null, new { @class = "???" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one below. You vary the col-md inside row as per your need

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productForm", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Edition", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-3">
               @Html.DropDownList("edition", (List<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.PossibleEditions, new { @class = "form-control", onchange="this.form.submit();" })
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
               @Html.ActionLink("Compare features", "Features", "ProductName", null, new { @class = "???" })
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```